# Searching a word for a specific character at a set point (Java)

Tags: java, junit, java.util.scanner

I am writing a method to search through a dicitionary to find multiple words of the same length that contain the same letter at a set point. I.e. All words of length 5 that have b as their second letter.

I'm writing this method by TDD is eclipse and so far my method is as follows:

```
    private OpenQueue openQueue = new OpenQueue();
    private boolean value;
    private int lengthOfWord, numberFound;
    private File inFile = new File("src/src/WordList"); //This is a text file

    public Search(int length) {
       this.lengthOfWord = length;
    }  

    public boolean examine2(int crossingPoint, char letter) {
       try {
         Scanner input = new Scanner(inFile);           
         while (input.hasNextLine()) { //while there are words left to be read
           String word = input.nextLine();      
           if(word.length() == lengthOfWord) { //if the word is of the right length
              while(word.charAt(crossingPoint-1) == letter){ 
                numberFound = numberFound + 1; //number of solutions is increased by one
                openQueue.add(word);//word is added to the open queue
                value = true; //value is true when at least one solution has been found
              }
           }
         }
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           System.out.println("They File was not Found");
           e.printStackTrace();
         }
        System.out.println(numberFound); //returns number of words found
        return value; //should return true if there is at least one word
    }
```

For my test I trying to find all five letter words that have a second letter b and there are several words that fit this as I've checked manually. However when I run JUnit it says that it expected true but it was false.

The code runs up to but not past the while(word.charAt(crossingPoint-1) == letter) loop, as previously I added in System.out.println("Here") before this loop to check were the code runs until.

I'm not sure how to fix this in order for the code to run without the test failing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How are you calling your function? What are the exact arguments?

Comment: Where is `lengthOfWord` defined?

Comment: I'm calling the function in a JUnit test by (Apologies about the formmatting):

private search searchFiveLetterWord= new Search(5);

@Test
public void findAFiveLetterWordThatHasSecondLetterB() {
assertEquals("Find a five letter word that has a second letter B and print out", true, searchFiveLetterWord.examine2(2, b)); 
}

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to look at this code -- arghh!  But there appear to be at least one syntax error.  I'm not sure whether you just copied it into this question incorrectly, otherwise I don't even see how it can compile.  You put parentheses after lengthOfWord which makes it look like a no-argument method or method call, but you appear to want to use it as an integer variable.

Also inFile and numberFound do not appear to be defined.  You will have to provide more context.